# How can I detect mouseup on top of an element when the click started on a different element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to detect when the mouse is released over a certain html element. I would like the mouseup event to fire no matter where the dragging started initially. Here is my attempt, which behaves very weirdly (sometimes it fires, sometimes not, sometimes I get two alerts):

```js
$("body").click(function() {
  $(".cube").mouseup(function() {
    console.log('mouseup')
  });
});
```

```css
.box,
.cube {
  background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cube {
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box"></div>

  <div class="cube"></div>
</body>
```

Problem number 2 demonstrated: the event is not firing after dragging starts from the upper div:

```js
  $(".cube").mouseup(function(){
      console.log('mouseup')
    });
```

```css
  .box{
        background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }

    .cube{
        background: #222;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box"></div>

  <div class="cube"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You're creating a mouseup handler every time you click. Rethink your logic on that. What is your click handler for, anyway?

Comment: @isherwood I was the click handler used on the official example here in the jQuery documentation: https://api.jquery.com/mouseup/ But if I can get the mouseup to fire reliably without the click, then that would be great. But for some reason my mouseup event stops firing when I originate the drag from another element.

Comment: The docs don't nest event handlers like you have. They _trigger_ the mouseup event. By passing in a function as an argument you convert it to a handler instead of an emitter.

Comment: Okay.. Any idea why this version of the code randomly stops firing on Chrome but works on Firefox:

    <script>
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.cube').on("mouseup", function(){
     
     console.log('mup');
          
    });
});

Comment: @isherwood Sorry, never created code snippets here before so I had no idea how to do it. Now it's included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's even simpler than what you made. You just only need

```
<script>
     $(".cube").mouseup(function(){
       alert('mouseup')
     });
</script>
```

If you release it, it means that you have clicked anywhere before

Comment: I assumed it would be something simple like this, but if you try this codepen and start the dragging from the upper cube, then the console logs weirdly stop happening: https://codepen.io/noip/pen/VwrrLoL?editors=1111

Comment: @user44109 hmm you are right, but notice this happens because the cursor changes to "not allowed" when you try to drag twice. If you click between drags, this does not happen

Comment: do you think this is a bug in jQuery?

Comment: @user44109 not sure about that. But what I've noticed is that this error occurs on chromium browsers, but not on Firefox